# Laplace $2$-D Heat Conduction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, heat-equation

Consider the following steady state problem

$$\Delta T = 0,\,\,\,\, (x,y) \in \Omega, \space \space 0 \leq x \leq 4 ,\space \space \space\space 0 \leq y \leq 2 $$

$$ T(0,y) = 300, \space \space T(4,y) = 600$$

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}(x,0) = 0, \space \space \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}(x,2) = 0$$

I want to derive the analytical solution to this problem.

1) Use separation of variables.

$$\frac{X^{''}}{X}= -\frac{Y^{''}}{Y} = -\lambda $$
$$X^{''} + \lambda X = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$Y^{''} - \lambda Y = 0 \tag{2}$$

The solution to $(2$) is

$Y(y) = C_1 \cos(ay)+C_2 \sin(ay)$

We find that 
$$C_2 = 0$$ and 
$$Y^{'}(2) = C_1\alpha \sin(2\alpha) = 0 \tag{3}$$

with $(3)$ giving that $\alpha = n\frac{\pi}{2}$

so $Y$ is given by

$$Y(y) = C_1sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}y)$$

The solution to $(1)$ is

$$X(x) = Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{-\alpha x}$$

where $\alpha$ is given by $\alpha = n\frac{\pi}{2}$

So the solution is:

$$u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y) = C_1sin(\alpha y)(Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{-\alpha x}) \tag{4}$$

where $\alpha$ is given by $\alpha = n\frac{\pi}{2}$

Inserting the B.C. in $(4)$ gives:

$$u(0,y) \implies E_n = \frac{300}{sin(\alpha y)}$$

$$u(4,y) \implies F_n = \frac{600}{G sin(\alpha y)Ae^{4 \alpha }+Hsin(\alpha y)e^{-4 \alpha }}$$

This is how far I have come. How do I continue?

Comment: This is just a little comment. As far as I was taught, you have to change your task a little bit: it's easier to work with equation $\Delta T = f(x, y)$ with homogeneous boundary conditions. So you find any sufficiently simple function $W(x, y)$ such that $T(x, y) - W(x, y)$ is homogeneous on boundaries and you check what differential equation $\Delta u = f(x, y)$ the $T(x, y) - W(x, y)$ satisfies. And then you use standard procedure to solve $\Delta u = f(x, y)$ with homogeneous boundary conditions.

Comment: @Evgeny I made a typo. The Neumman conditions are supposed to be zero

Comment: Yeah, but Dirichlet conditions are still nonhomogeneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

1) Start from here

$$Y^{''} - \lambda Y = 0\\  
Y^{'}(0)=Y^{'}(4)=0$$

find the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and the eigenfunctions $Y_i(y)$.

2) Find the $X_i(x)$

$$X^{''} + \lambda X = 0$$

3) Form the infinite sum

$$T(x,y) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {{X_i}(x){Y_i}(y)} $$

4) Apply boundary conditions

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {{X_i}(0){Y_i}(y)}  = 100  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {{X_i}(2){Y_i}(y)}  = 200 \cr} $$

5) Find unknown constants using the orthogonality property of $Y_{i}(y)$

$$\int\limits_0^4 {{Y_i}(y){Y_j}(y)dy}  = {\delta _{ij}}\int\limits_0^4 {Y_i^2(y)dy} $$

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @DoubleOseven: I updated my hints. :)

Comment: @DoubleOseven: Hey OP! Where are you? :)

Comment: @ H.R. Hi I haven't really managed to come to a solution. I know that you have provided an answer but I cant really come to a solution. Feels like I am being a pain if I say once again that I need more hints

Comment: @DoubleOseven: So I suggest you to write your solution step by step in the question and clarify in which step you are stuck. Then I can help you. :)

Comment: @ H.R. I have updated my question. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @DoubleOseven: Your problem is in your equation $(4)$. Compare it with the step $(3)$ in my answer. :)

Comment: @ H.R. Thank you I have finally came to an answer :) appreciate your help in figuring this out. You was right it was step $4$ that went wrong

Comment: @DoubleOseven: You are welcome! :) Happy to hear that! :) Would you please, vote up or accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Sort of guide**

1. Transform the equation such that it'll have homogeneous boundary conditions.
   I suggest to use $W(x, y) = 100 + 50x$ : this is the simplest function that has $W(0, y) = 100$, $W(2, y) = 200$ and by the way $\frac{\partial W}{\partial y} \equiv 0$. What will happen to solutions of original equation if we subtract $W(x, y)$ ? Let's see:
   $$\Delta (T - W) = \Delta T - \Delta W = 0 - 0 = 0. $$
   So, $T-W$ solves the equation $\Delta u = 0$, but with homogeneous boundary conditions of the same type.
2. From separation of variables you have that you are trying to find solutions of form $u(x, y) = X(x) \cdot Y(y)$ such that they satisfy boundary conditions and $\Delta u = 0$. This leads to following equations:
   $$ X'' = - \lambda X $$
   $$ Y'' = \lambda Y $$
   plus boundary conditions. Because we want to find non-trivial solutions to this equation, boundary conditions yield:
   $$ u(0, y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow X(0) Y(y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow X(0) = 0 $$
   $$ u(2, y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow X(2) Y(y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow X(2) = 0 $$
   $$ u'_{y}(x, 0) = 0 \Leftrightarrow X(x) Y'(0) = 0 \Leftrightarrow Y'(0) = 0 $$
   $$ u'_{y}(x, 4) = 0 \Leftrightarrow X(x) Y'(4) = 0 \Leftrightarrow Y'(4) = 0 $$
   Then you find for what values of $\lambda$ you can satisfy these boundary conditions. You will obtain a countable (or empty) set of such 'eigenvalues' $\lambda_k$ with corresponding functions $X_k$ and $Y_k$ (each depends on two parameters -- that is because they are general solutions of second order ODE.
3. Find the solution in form $U(x, y) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} X_k (x) \cdot Y_k (y) $. Any finite or infinite sum of such functions satisfy Laplace equation and boundary conditions, so you just have to determine coefficients in $X_k$ and $Y_k$.
4. Don't forget to add $W(x, y)$ to $U(x, y)$ :)

Comment: I think your $W(x,y)=100+50x$ is the answer as it satisfies all the boundary conditions and also the PDE and due to uniqueness it is the only solution. :)

Comment: @H.R.  Heh, I realized that too after some time :) but I just wanted to show the method and haven't thought that first guess for transforming equation would be the final answer....